# How to put an image on the right side of a proof?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I tried but I don't know how to put an image  beside a proof like this
[image]

Edit: Please don't worry about the mathematics and the shape of the figure. My question is; How can I put a "proof"(\begin{proof}) and a figure side by side. You may use this one

[image]

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\marginpar{...\captionof{figure}{...}}` in conjunction with the package `caption`.

Comment: Did you try to use wrapfigure?

Comment: Or `minipage`s with `\captionof` if it shouldn't go in the margin but take space from the body text.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin `proof` is probably defined as a list which means you cannot use `wrapfigure` anywhere near it, let alone alongside it.

Comment: how about `multicol` package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this solution (without claiming to be complete):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{amsthm}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
    \renewenvironment{proof}[3][\proofname]{\par
        \pushQED{\qed}%
        \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
        {\noindent\textit{#1}\@addpunct{.}\hspace{\the\labelsep}}%
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            #2
            \caption{#3}
        \end{wrapfigure}%
        \ignorespaces
    }{%
        \popQED\@endpefalse
        \par
        \vspace*{\the\parsep}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}{\includegraphics{}}{This is caption.\label{fig:1}}
This is a proof. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteruer adipiscing elit.
\end{proof}


This is figure~\ref{fig:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This is only a point of departure because I am sure that there are more elegant solutions to your question.